# Ajax ModalPopUp Window according to certain conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a Ajax ModalPopupExtender in my page.On a button click currently using TargetControlId i am showing the pop up.My need is when i am clicking the button want to check some conditions from DB.If condition satisfies i want to show the pop up.Other wise no need of pop up.How can i do this?

```
 <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender CancelControlID="btnCancel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" runat="server" ID="PopupExtender"  TargetControlID="btn"  PopupControlID="Panel1"></ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     if (MyCondition == true)
        {           
           modalPopUpConfirmation.Show();
        }
     else
        {            
            Label1.Text = "The condition was false, so no modal popup!";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     PopupExtender.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call it dynamically.

```
<!-- Hidden Field -->
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidForModel" runat="server" />

<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender CancelControlID="btnCancel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" runat="server" ID="PopupExtender"  TargetControlID="hidForModel"  PopupControlID="Panel1"></ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Button ID="btnShowPopup" runat="server" Text="Save Data"
            OnClick="btnShowPopup_Click" />
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void btnShowPopup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(Yourcondition)
  {
     PopupExtender.Show();
  }
}
```